# How can I permanently fix /dev/vchiq permission errors?

Tags: permissions

I am working on writing a graphical application that uses the Pi's GPU, and I constantly get `* failed to open vchiq instance` errors when running my programs.  This is usually fixed by a `sudo chmod 777 /dev/vchiq`, but (1) this is a very insecure fix that is definitely not suited to deployment to user-owned devices, and (2) it gets reset after each reboot.

How can I fix my `/dev/vchiq` problems "the right way", persistently, without introducing security issues?

Answer (score 32):

I was able to solve a similar problem by adding myself to the `video` group (I was not using the default user). Maybe this can help.

The command is:

```
sudo usermod -a -G video $(whoami)
```

You will need to log out and in again for the change to take effect.

Comment: This worked for me (`sudo usermod -a -G video $(whoami)`), I would also recommend (for security purposes) adding a dedicated user for whatever process will need access to the camera and adding only that user to the `video` group.

Comment: After rebooting, this permanent solution works fine and is relatively safe.

Comment: Reboot required....

Comment: This worked for me too! Thanks. Reboot is not necessary, logging out and logging in again is enough.

Comment: This is the proper, secure way to do it.  If you have a dedicated user for this function, you can add them by replacing $(whoami) with that username.

Comment: You can just execute `su - $USER` if you don't want to reboot or logout/login.

Answer (score 9):

You can create a udev rule to set specific permissions on the device. As root, you could:

```
echo 'SUBSYSTEM=="vchiq",GROUP="video",MODE="0660"' > /etc/udev/rules.d/10-vchiq-permissions.rules
usermod -a -G video YourUnprivilegedUser
```

Comment: This does not fix the problem. After running that, I still get the error.

Comment: I suspect the permissions are done in a higher (thus later in the running order) udev rule which undos this change.  On my (Debian) PC the system supplied file is `/lib/udev/rules.d/91-permissions.rules` so I'd try writing this to an even higher one (and perhaps include local in the name to identify it as a local modification), i.e.: `echo \`SUBSYSTEM=="vchiq",GROUP="video",MODE="0660"\' > /etc/udev/rules.d/92-local-vchiq-permissions.rules`

Comment: I get permission denied, what might be wrong?

Comment: Works perfectly for me. Elegant solution if usermod isn't enough

Answer (score 5):

You could set `SUID` permission

```
sudo chmod u+s /dev/vchiq
```

Comment: What does this do?

Comment: When an executable file has been given the `setuid` attribute, normal users on the system who have permission to execute this file gain the privileges of the user who owns the file (commonly root).

You could set this on your program (assuming it is owned by root).

As `/dev/vchiq` belongs to group `video` another option is to set `setgid` and the group on your program to `video`.

Comment: That didn't help, albeit user `www-data` is in `video` group, but I succeeded with `chmod a+rw /dev/vchiq` on Raspbian Stretch.

Answer (score 3):

If you are running raspistill from a php script accessed via a browser then you need to enter: `sudo usermod -a -G video www-data`
to give Apache the necessary permissions.

Comment: as said above, reboot required, but thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

add

```
start_x=1 
gpu_mem=256
```

to `boot/config.txt` then run `sudo raspistill -o cam.jpg`

Of course I added the path for the raspistill. It worked for me in Ubuntu.

Comment: I do not see how this answers the OP's question - could you expand your answer to explain how it works on the Raspberry Pi?